# iPhone app converting to iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface, builder

I want to convert my app to a Universal app. Can anyone recommend some good tutorials for achieving this?

I need to have each View in Interface Builder as a separate, view for iPhone or iPad.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a WWDC 2010 video on this.... check this years titles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just did this mostly manually, using approximately the following steps:

Load the app's main window xib in Interface Builder, use the IB menu "Create iPad Version" to convert it to an iPad version, and save it under an appropriate name (a "-iPad.xib" suffix is common.)

In Xcode, add this new .xib file to your project and include it in the app's target.

Modify the app's Info.plist to name this new ipad xib under the "NSMainNibFile~ipad" key.

Change the Build target setting to say iPhone/iPad as the targeted device.

Add run-time code checks such as:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { ... }
```

to handle any programmatically created UI or drawing differences, select iPhone versus iPad xibs, etc.

Add appropriate icon sizes, default images, etc.

Redesign your views to optionally display more stuff, autoresize to support more rotations, use popovers, etc.

Comment: Any idea where  "Create iPad Version" would be in Xcode 4.2?

Comment: Don't forget to set Devices to "Universal" in your project's iOS Application Target settings.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad) is the tutorial I've used a few times.  It's very easy to follow.

Comment: TThanks but I am actually wanting a tutorial that would allow me to have two separate XIB files each for iPhone or iPad.

Comment: But it does...  It creates a MainWindow-iPad.xib and sets everything up so it loads that up in the iPad sim and the iPhone version in the iPhone sim.