# How to make a application with target is iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, deployment

I want to make **a application** which can run complete in iPhone and iPad (full mode, not x2 mode). Please help me. Thank in advance!
I found down a config called "Targeted Device Family", but I still don't know what about design (for iPhone, iPad), how to show UI if device is iPhone, how to show UI if device is iPad.

Answer (score 2):

See "Creating a Universal Application" in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.htmlhttp://) for details on how to set this up in Xcode, and what pieces you need to provide.

Answer (score 1):

**Target Device Family: iPad/iPhone.** 
You need then two xib-Files if you want two different designs.
One for the iPad Resolution and one for the iPad resolution.
Like MainWindow-iPad.xib and MainWindow-iPhone.xib or you implement a recognition of the device in your code.

For more information look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069674/iphone-app-converting-to-ipad) thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Universal iOS app :) google "convert iPhone app into universal app". Things get a lot easier when your project is done in interface builder.