# Is it possible to develop a fullscreen iPad application with Phonegap?

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

I wanted to develop an iPad app with Phonegap and I stumbled upon the fact that it won't run in fullscreen (it will have the screensize of an iPhone). Is there any hack to prevent this?

Comment: you need to create an ipad project not iphone project

Answer (score 0):

Its possible. You need to specify that the app is an iPad app in your Xcode project configuration. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984044/how-to-make-a-application-with-target-is-iphone-ipad?rq=1)